# Streaming URL Encoder

Tags: java

In my Java app, I'm looking for a streaming version of [URLEncoder.encode(String s, String enc)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).  I'd like to stream a large HTTP post request using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type.  Does such a thing exist either in a library, or an open source project?  Or is there an easy way to implement it?

This was an early attempt, but is incorrect because it doesn't handle UTF codepoints larger than one byte:

```
// Incorrect attempt at creating a URLEncoder OutputStream
private class URLEncoderOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream
{
    public URLEncoderOutputStream(OutputStream out)
    {
        super(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException
    {
        String s = new String(new byte[] { (byte)b });
        String enc = URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");
        out.write(enc.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to send? A very large text the user enters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that OutputStreams don't know anything about characters, only bytes.  What you really want is a *Writer*, e.g.

```
public class URLEncodedWriter extends FilterWriter {
    public void write(int c) {
        out.write(URLEncoder.encode((char)c, "UTF-8"));
    }
    ... // Same for 2 other write() methods
}
```

Comment: I know I'm a decade late to this, but I want to say thank you so much for this answer.  This is normally the type of scenario on stackoverflow where I see someone give a smart alec response, but you took it seriously, and this actually just helped me with a different streaming issue I was having.  So massive, massive thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is I shouldn't be trying to do this.  According to the [HTML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4):

> The content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is inefficient for sending large quantities of binary data or text containing non-ASCII characters. The content type "multipart/form-data" should be used for submitting forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and binary data.

Most servers will reject HTTP headers that exceed a certain length in any case.

Comment: Yes, Apache will truncate at 8kB of headers.  You can pass as much in the body as you want though when doing a POST.

Comment: Would the content in this case be be part of the header or body of the request?